# Seeking jQuery LightBox grid plugIns

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just wondering if anybody knows of any jQuery Lightbox type plugins for photo galleries, where are images are displayed in a grid type format which then the user can click on an image which zooms to the forefront and back again?

Something similar to iPhoto Gallery on the Mac OS X platform but just want all the photos displayed to the user which they can then click on.

Answer (score 0):

The library that most get closer of iPhoto's zoom in and out is Highslide Js and FancyBox:

```
highslide.com

highslide.com/ref/hs.easing

fancybox.net/
```

And for the gallery effects to expand or minimize the grid view, try jquery UI Slider:

jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Here we have something like this:

```
webdesignledger.com/tutorials/create-a-resizable-image-grid-with-jquery

And the result:
demos.webdesignledger.com/jquery_image_grid/example2.htm
```